# React | Focus on child textarea when parent clicked WITHOUT being "anti-pattern"

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component with a child component that contains a textarea.

```
function Parent(){
    function handleClick(){
        //I want to make the child textarea focus
    }

    return(
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
             <Child/>
        </div>
    );
}

function Child(){
    return(
        <textarea value="Input"></textarea>
    );
}
```

The comment in handleClick() explains what I want to do. I know that I could use a reference of child to call a function manually, however, this seems to be anti-pattern of typical React.

Is there a better way to go about this than using references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can approach it is through props. I didn't test it, but if you have any problem with it I can check it on a codesandbox for you.

```
function Parent(){
    const [hasFocus, setHasFocus] = useState(false)

    function handleClick(){
        setHasFocus(true)
    }

    function onBlur() {
        setHasFocus(false)
    }

    return(
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
             <Child hasFocus={hasFocus} onBlur={onBlur} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
function Child({hasFocus, onBlur}){
    const textArea = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (hasFocus && textArea.current) textArea.current.focus()
    }, [hasFocus])

    return(
        <textarea ref={textArea} value="Input" onBlur={onBlur}></textarea>
    );
}
```